# Can we set a tablename by checking a if else condition in SQL and as well as HQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, hql

I have to set a particular table name(consider multiple tables) by checking a column in table1 where there will be a String which can be mapped to any of that multiple tables. So if the String is matching a name then set or check a if else statement to set a particular table name.

In simple language

```
select tableNAme.name  
from yert  
if  (yert.name = 'hello' then set tableName = 'hello_table')  
else (yert.name = 'hi' then set tableName = 'hi_table')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *RDBMS* manages tables and columns. It hence uses system tables holding table names, column names, column types etc.

*You* manage, say, employees, items, orders, pictures, whatever. *You* don't manage tables. So you should have no tables that contain table names. (Exception: you might do that for logging purpose.)

It seems hence, you choose a bad data model and I'd recommend changing it. However, even with such a data model it is possible to work. You'd use outer joins to access whatever table is linked.

```
select 
  yert.value, 
  coalesce(hello_table.description, hi_table.description)
from yert
left join hello_table 
  on yert.tablename= 'hello_table' and yert.table_id = hello_table.id
left join hi_table 
  on yert.tablename= 'hi_table' and yert.table_id = hi_table.id;
```